# How to serve VueJS 3 Hello World application as a lib?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I'm using:

- NodeJS: 16.6.1
- VueJS: 3.0.0
- Vue CLI: 4.15.13

Using CLI, I setup the "hello world" app and tried to build it using the `lib` target using:

```
npx vue-cli-service build --target lib --name helloworld ./src/components/HelloWorld.vue --mode production
```

The build works fine and produces content in the `./dist` directory.  Visiting it from a regular HTTP server I was expecting the demo.html file to render the component properly but it didn't.  **A JS error is thrown**:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: vue is not defined
```

The console warns that Vue is running in development mode, but CLI is supposed to be in production mode by default.  Am I missing something?

I'm trying VueJS for the first time and try to understand how to produce a library out of components that could then be used in other projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vue CLI 4.5.13 does not create Vue 3 compatible demos. For instance, [version 4.5.13 still uses Vue 2 initialization in `demo.html`](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/blob/v4/packages/@vue/cli-service/lib/commands/build/demo-lib.html). Version 5.x [fixes this](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/commit/20355435e7b0ca59c1584d249cfad1abbac396c8).

Install `@vue/cli` 5.x instead to create Vue 3 libraries (`@next` is currently `5.0.0-beta.3`):

```sh
npm i -g @vue/cli@next
```

> The console warns that Vue is running in development mode, but CLI is supposed to be in production mode by default. Am I missing something?

The library build externalizes `vue` by default (it's not bundled with the library). Instead, `demo.html` pulls it in from CDN:

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
```

That resolves to `https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.14/dist/vue.js` (the latest version as of today), which is a development build. If you prefer the production build, change the `src` URL to the minified build:

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.14/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Using the correct Vue CLI version solved the issues I had indeed (the name of the package is `@vue/cli@next`).  For the production build of vue 3, I used: `<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.2.1/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>`.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: I've created a PR for the Vue CLI doc to mention this.  https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/pull/6630  Having known about that from reading it in the doc would have avoided the issue in the first place.  Thanks a lot again @tony19 for your help.